# Disable nsILoginManagerPrompter for Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

I have an extension that uses `addon-sdk` and an HTML/JavaScript popup form for logging in, and I keep getting this error in the Browser Console when I click 'Log In'.

```
[Exception... "'PopupNotifications_show: invalid browser' when calling method: [nsILoginManagerPrompter::promptToSavePassword]"  nsresult: "0x8057001e (NS_ERROR_XPC_JS_THREW_STRING)"  location: "JS frame :: resource://gre/modules/LoginManagerContent.jsm :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 551"  data: no]
```

The login works after about 3 tries, but it is frustrating for clients to have to enter their info into the form several times.

It is impossible for a user to have their password saved via this kind of form anyway, so I just want to know if there is a way to disable it using the `addon-sdk` or something similar.

Or, should I remove the form and validate via AJAX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by removing the form and using AJAX for validation.